# SQL Statement is too complex for Microsoft Access, after I changed the Source to a DB

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote an sql query with a subselect in Microsoft Access and tried it with local tables and it worked perfectly. But then i changed the source to a table that is linked to an SQL Server DB and all of a sudden it tells me that the statement is too complex. It only has a group by, subselect and SUM. I dont understand why the source of the table makes a difference in the complexity. I dont know what to do.

```
PARAMETERS [von Datum] DateTime, [bis Datum] DateTime;

SELECT Sum(auftraege.Netto) AS NettoAuftraege, (SELECT Sum(angebote.Netto) 
                                                FROM angebote 
                                                WHERE angebote.Verkaeufer IS NOT NULL and
                                                ((angebote.Date) Between [von Datum] And [bis Datum])) AS NettoAngebote, 
                                                round((NettoAuftraege/NettoAngebote),2) AS Prozent
FROM auftraege
WHERE ((auftraege.Date) Between [von Datum] And [bis Datum]) and auftraege.Verkaeufer IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the SQL you want to execute in first place? That would trigger Select Sum(angebote.Netto) ... unnecessarily N times, no?

Comment: @CetinBasoz How would you do it? I have two tables with different values for Netto but the Seller(Verkäufer) are the same. My goal is to get an overview that is something like:  (Seller)John; (Angebote) 1200.40€; (Aufträge) 300.20€; and that for every Seller

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are doing would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(would be a mess as a comment. Disclaimer: I am not a fan of access, syntax might be wrong for access, like missing parentheses)

```
PARAMETERS [von Datum] DateTime, [bis Datum] DateTime;

select NZ(x.seller, y.seller) as seller,
   x.NettoAufTrage, y.NettoAngebote, round((x.NettoAuftraege/y.NettoAngebote),2) AS Prozent
from 
(
SELECT seller, Sum(Netto) AS NettoAuftraege  
FROM auftraege
WHERE ((auftraege.Date) Between [von Datum] And [bis Datum]) and auftraege.Verkaeufer IS NOT NULL
group by seller
) x
full join 
(
   SELECT seller, Sum(angebote.Netto) as NettoAngebote
   FROM angebote 
   WHERE angebote.Verkaeufer IS NOT NULL and 
   ((angebote.Date) Between [von Datum] And [bis Datum]))
   group by seller
) x on x.Seller = y.Seller;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution seems to work!